# How to get correctly localised display name for macOS Trash/Bin in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to get Swift to correctly return the local name for the Trash (eg since macOS 10.14/10.15, the Trash is now called Bin in many countries.)

My attempt simply returns "Trash" despite me being in a "Bin" place :)

```swift
let trashUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .trashDirectory, in: .allDomainsMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let trashName = FileManager.default.displayName(atPath: trashUrl.path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would work if you had added your local language as one of the localisations of your app. For example, my macOS system language is Japanese, and if I add Japanese to the localisations in project settings:

[image]

printing `trashName` from your code would give "ゴミ箱".

Essentially, `displayName(for:)` is getting the localised name in your app's current localisation. If your app can't be localised to your system's locale, it will stay in English, right? That's why it will show "Trash", unless you make your app able to be localised to whatever locale you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added all the available "English (*)" localisations, and now instead of "Trash" my code above returns "Delete". So weird :) Any thoughts? I just want to show a dialog saying "The item could not be opened because it is in the bin". Probably I should be localising the entire message, but this seemed like it should be a quick win before going full-l10n.

Comment: @jeff-h What is your system locale (`Locale.current`)? Did "all the available 'English (*)' localisations" include your system locale? If it didn't, then it might have used one that is closest to your system locale (I'm not sure about this), and that happens to call "Trash" "Delete". Also, I think the API is designed specifically so as to discourage you from doing this "quick win".

Comment: My current locale is `en_NZ`, so you're right, it isn't in one of the `en` locales I had added (`GB`, `AU`, `IN`) which I added because they were in the primary locales list in Xcode. I find it hard to believe any English-speaking country would say "Your file is in the Delete" (lol) and as such it seems a very weird fallback. Anyway, I will follow your wisdom and remove this code altogether, and do l10n properly when the time comes. Thanks again!